# W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null Android Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am facing this problem since 2 days and i didn't find any helpful solution, every time i signUp or SignIn using email, Password this what happen:

**W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.**

response come after 4-5 minute.

I tried many emulators one of them worked fine and the other not,
emulators APIs:
33: didn't work
30: didn't work
28: Worked
26: didn't work

My Code:

```
package com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app.fragments;

import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app.R;
import com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app.activites.MainActivity;
import com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app.activites.authentication;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuthException;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import javax.annotation.Nullable;

public class fragmentSignIn extends Fragment {

    //Fields
    TextView signUpTextView;
    EditText emailField;
    EditText passwordField;
    //Buttons
    Button signInButton;

    //Firebase
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    FirebaseFirestore db;

    //Others
    View view;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup parent, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Defines the xml file for the fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_sign_in, parent, false);

        setup();

        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Check email
                if (emailField.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    toast("Please enter your email");
                    return;
                }
                if ((!emailField.getText().toString().contains("@")) || (!emailField.getText().toString().contains(".com"))) {
                    toast("Invalid email format");
                    return;
                }
                //Check password
                if (passwordField.getText().toString().matches("")) {
                    toast("Please enter your password");
                    return;
                }
                if(getActivity()!=null){
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                }
                signIn();
            }
        });

        signUpTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                authentication registration = (authentication) getActivity();
                fragmentSignUp fragmentSignUp = new fragmentSignUp();
                assert registration != null;
                registration.replaceFragment(fragmentSignUp);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    // This event is triggered soon after onCreateView().
    // Any view setup should occur here.  E.g., view lookups and attaching view listeners.
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Setup any handles to view objects here
        // EditText etFoo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.etFoo);
    }

    void setup() {
        //Fields
        signUpTextView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.signUp);
        emailField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.emailField);
        passwordField = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.passwordField);

        //Buttons
        signInButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.signInButton);

        //Firebase
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
        FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            checkUserApproval(currentUser);
        }


    }

    void signIn() {
        String email = emailField.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordField.getText().toString();

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(getActivity(), new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                            if (user != null) {
                                checkUserApproval(user);
                            }
                        } else {
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    void updateUI(int x) {
        if (x == 0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        } else {
            authentication authentication = (authentication) getActivity();
            fragmentWaiting fragmentWaiting = new fragmentWaiting();
            assert authentication != null;
            authentication.replaceFragment(fragmentWaiting);
        }
    }


    void toast(String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }

    private void checkUserApproval(FirebaseUser user) {
        DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(user.getUid());
        docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                    if (document.exists()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
                        if (document.get("approval").toString().matches("Not yet")) {
                            updateUI(1);
                        } else {
                            updateUI(0);
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "No such document");

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });


    }

}
```

**Run:**

```
08/14 09:57:53: Launching 'app' on Pixel 5 API 26.
App restart successful without requiring a re-install.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app/com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app.activites.authentication" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 10716 on device 'Pixel_5_API_26 [emulator-5554]'.
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/FirebaseApp: Device unlocked: initializing all Firebase APIs for app [DEFAULT]
I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
W/zygote64: Skipping duplicate class check due to unrecognized classloader
I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:78 and remote module com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite:15
I/DynamiteModule: Selected local version of com.google.android.gms.measurement.dynamite
V/FA: onActivityCreated
V/FA: App measurement collection enabled
V/FA: App measurement enabled for app package, google app id: com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app, 1:938336016999:android:1e16856c037883e29f12c2
I/FA: App measurement initialized, version: 68000
I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.abdulghffar.gju_outgoings_app
D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=29KB, data=26KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=27KB, data=25KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 4323080
I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
D/: HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x74aee132c0, tid 10768
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x74b99cb5a0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x74b99cb5a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x74b99ff900)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x74b99cb5a0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0x74b99ff900)
D/FA: Connected to remote service
V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 5
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=59KB, data=52KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=59KB, data=52KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
W/View: dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(): not laid out, ignoring
I/AssistStructure: Flattened final assist data: 2264 bytes, containing 1 windows, 8 views
I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=124KB, data=103KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=108KB, data=63KB
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
W/System: Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=123KB, data=83KB
I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=123KB, data=83KB
I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 512KB
I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 6MB to compile void android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals()
W/ContentValues: signInWithEmail:failure
    com.google.firebase.FirebaseNetworkException: A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztu.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:17)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzus.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:9)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzut.zzl(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuq.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:25)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzts.zzh(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzqh.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzvb.zza(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:16)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuh.zzs(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzrx.zzC(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:5)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztt.zzw(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:8)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zztb.zzc(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase-auth-api.zzuu.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@21.0.6:1)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?

Comment: @AlexMamo The login and registration in my app does not work when I use an emulator with an Android API below 30. The message I get when I call the login method is *W/System: Header X-Firebase-Locale is ignored because its value is null*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem only occurs when you use the emulator but on the actual device it's working and updating firebase authentication and realtime database as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**Update: Okay I still get this message, but everything is working again. I'm using a Ryzen CPU and installed the "android emulator hypervisor driver for amd processors". Together with the latest emulator patches, everything is working again.**

I have the same problem and can only test an a real device since the emulator won't connect to Firebase after succesful Google Sign In.

Additionally I now upgraded my dependencies and the Anrdoird Target SDK.
Also the manifest containst the cleartext attribute.

Nonetheless this is currently not working.